# finding the best conjunctions in logistic regression?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

I'm trying my hand at a logistic regression model. I have about 60 features and now would like to try conjunctions of features. Is there a good (principled) way to explore the space of all pairs, triples, etc., short of trying all possible combinations? The data set is large (10s of millions of examples), so I can go as deep as 4- or 5-feature combinations.

Comment: Interesting question, but not about programming at all. Voting to migrate it to stats.

Comment: Not sure how I'd do that. N00b here.